# How to make asynchronous call synchronous

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, synchronization

We have an existing web service, with basically 2 calls: submitWork, pickupResponse. A client of the web service submits task to be processed by calling submitWork() that gives a transactionId response, and then periodically calls the pickupResponse() with the transactionId to actually get the result. Inside the server, the work gets performed in several different processes, some event driven, and it takes about 15 seconds to be completed.
The new business request is to make that process to be in a synchronized call, meaning, the client will call newSubmitWork() and that call, as along as it takes, will provide the final response.
The basic implementation would be: wrap those 2 old executions in one logic, submit work and then wait/loop to pickup the response. That makes the new web service call to basically take a time of about 15 seconds. Such a long call would cause various issues in the server, in the scenario of multiple concurrent requests. Such as, using too many threads, or of no threads available then timeouts. Or, the most severe scenario, where call gets to the server, starts processing, but the client gets timeout, although logic is actually done.
**I am looking for alternative solutions or practices for such a case, so please advise on that.**


The several options discussed already internally:

1. Rewrite internal processes to be able to work synchronous - will take too long, too expensive and high risk for new bugs.
2. Instead of locking the call, suggest the WS client to send them a call back with result - in this case, all WS clients will actually need to implement logic on their side to handle that call.
3. Raise server resources, memory and threads - which I personally believe is not efficient, as it still has the risk of high message amount, more than server can take.
4. Make a contract with the client that will not send more than X messages at Y time - that's nice, until the point the client will break the contract.
5. Build a gateway WS, on our side, that will know the amount of current requests in process and will drop incoming requests when knowing there is a high chance of timeout to happen.

Comment: Is below approach feasible? 1) In your web service, spawn a separate thread to take care of both tasks. 2) Show some message to the user "Your request will be processed" just after starting thread 3) Show actual result after 15 seconds

Comment: @sunrise76 this approach still keeps the problem of long wait and if there will be many concurrent requests the server will overload.

Comment: I am curious on type of your services, taking 15 seconds for completion of a transaction. Can you provide insight on which sub task is taking that much time along with total hops for completion of both these tasks?

Comment: @sunrise76 this is a distributed, in some cases event driven, business logic transactions. It involves MQ communication, outgoing web services calls, etc. Most of the time of those 15 seconds is actually for waiting for events, etc. In a case where this whole logic will be transformed to sequential/sync processing, the whole thing will not take more than an actual second. This is a legacy process, and at this point it is unlikely to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is the most clean solution if you can afford the extra Dev to make it Synch.
2. I would definitly go for that solution if you don't have the resources to go for soltion #1.
3. How much should you raise the resource? What about when your app gets a high load? Nothing will guarantee the execution time. This solution will definitly lead to intermitent exceptions.
4. X and Y would depend on how much load your server gets when a call is made. Too many variables that you don't control. Not a good solution.
5. I don't understand how this would make your 2 services Synch.

I would definitly go for solution #2 if your are in a rush. Although, your code will be harder to read with a callback. Otherwise #1 is best as your remove all unecessary assynch logic in your app.

Comment: 1. Currently looks like a big NO NO on that one 2. cool, thanks 3. This is indeed the biggest problem, we are not sure what to expect and what is the maximum expected load. 4. right. 5. This is to protect the already synched process form overloading.

Comment: I would only adjust the timeout of the client for a reasonable value. The client will know there is a big load on the server if the request times out. Otherwise, if you drop the request, it will look like everything is fine from the client perspective.

Comment: I don't see how a long client timeout solves the problem. Say client defines X seconds timeout, his request waits for the server to start processing for X-1 seconds (while server has no available threads), server starts processing and after 1 seconds client gets the timeout...